# Bind Alt+Shift to Ctrl button

Tags: javascript, access-keys

How can you do this in javascript:
press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Button but return a <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> down. 
I am doing this because firefox access key is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> its so hard. I want to bind <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>
to single button which is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

try to use smth like this

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    e = e || event;
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
     //do action    
    }

}
```

Comment: what code to put in "do action" so that it return an ALT+SHIFT?

Comment: Accesskey is browser specific. Your users should be familiar with the browser they use.